# Real space description/information of photons

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

recently I read a paper about some special tratment in QED (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.193603) and they used a lot the term "real space description" or "real space information" of photons. So my question is, what do the authors mean by that exactly?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This means the real space (position space), and not complex or momentum space.

Please see here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09595.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space